# Yii Framework - CHtml

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

I'm new to the Yii Framework.  In fact, it was dumped on my lap last week.  On the email confirmation I need to print "number" of posts. For example, 3 posts.

The problem I'm not sure how to count the posts and print it on the confirmation.  Do I add the db query to the controller instead of the form?  And then print out the number of posts like below?  -

```
<?php echo $posts->count($posts);
```

I'm just a little confused using a framework.  I need a little push.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's been quite a while since I have used yii so I'm a little rusty.

I'm going to make an assumption: `$post` is extended from [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)
the count function being used by your CActiveRecord requires a sql condition ([noted here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail)).

My next assumption is that you are preparing all this business logic in your view and not in the controller. You might consider sending from the view to a decorator, for your email confirmation message.

This is untested, but below we need to compare all the pk of posts:

`echo $posts->count('fieldDate < now() AND fieldDate >' . strtotime('yesterday'));`

Better and easier might be:

`echo $posts->countByAttributes(array('postID'));`

If you are looking to count all posts by an author (also untested):

`$numberOfPosts = count(PostModel::model()->findAll("author_id=$authorId"));`

Otherwise you might try:
`count($posts);` If you are receiving an array of post objects that have be queried in a previous controller in the view.

Fat model, thin controller.

Comment: Actually after looking around there is a function in the controller.  The controller gets the first name, last name  etc which is coming from the form...

Comment: @user4543794 What are you trying to accomplish? Number of posts based on author id?

Comment: Yes from the author id.

Comment: @user4543794 You probably want: `$numberOfPosts = count(PostModel::model()->findAll("author_id=$authorId"));`